# Is there an alternative way to replace nested for-loops and make R code more fast and efficient?

Tags: r

I have three data frames, and want to find combinations of some of the rows from these three dfs which meet the criteria:

```
df_1[i, "start"] == df_2[j, "start"] &
  df_1[i, "end"] == df_3[k, "end"] &
  df_2[j, "end"] < df_3[k, "start"]
```

I used nested for loop to do this job, but it takes a very long time to get the results. I am wondering is there a better way to select the rows from each of the data frames?

```
df_pos.D.DA.A.subDA<-df_pos.D.DA.A[df_pos.D.DA.A$anchor=="DA",]
df_pos.D.DA.A.subD<-df_pos.D.DA.A[df_pos.D.DA.A$anchor=="D",] 
df_pos.D.DA.A.subA<-df_pos.D.DA.A[df_pos.D.DA.A$anchor=="A",]

junction.pos.DA<-NULL
junction.pos.D<-NULL
junction.pos.A<-NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(df_pos.D.DA.A.subDA)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(df_pos.D.DA.A.subD)){
    for (k in 1:nrow(df_pos.D.DA.A.subA)){
      DAs<-df_pos.D.DA.A.subDA[i,"start"]
      DAe<-df_pos.D.DA.A.subDA[i,"end"]
      Ds<-df_pos.D.DA.A.subD[j,"start"]
      De<-df_pos.D.DA.A.subD[j,"end"]
      As<-df_pos.D.DA.A.subA[k,"start"]
      Ae<-df_pos.D.DA.A.subA[k,"end"]
      if((DAs==Ds)&(DAe==Ae)&(De<As)) {
      junction.pos.DA[i]<-df_pos.D.DA.A.subDA[i,"name"];
      junction.pos.D[j]<-df_pos.D.DA.A.subD[j,"name"];
      junction.pos.A[k]<-df_pos.D.DA.A.subA[k,"name"];
      print(c(i,j,k))
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If some operations only depend on `i` or `j` why put them in the inner loop? Like this you are repeating the same code over and over again.

Comment: Even more,  why are these loops nested. None of the statements involving k make mention of I or j. This should just be three consecutive loops.

Comment: Are the data-frames so large that you can't merge/filter/merge/filter/filter them together?

Comment: Is `start` <= `end` in any given data-frame?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Instead of nested for loop, I use left_join function from dplyr package get this analysis done!